# UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE Next js on k8s API

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, next.js

I have .NET api deploying in container on k8s with valid certificate. [image]

Everything was working good until I needed to make request from the server side of application within `getServerSideProps()`, when I started getting this error:

```
TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11576:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  cause: Error: unable to verify the first certificate
      at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1550:34)
      at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:514:28)
      at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:967:8)
      at ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:743:12)
      at TLSWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
    code: 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE'
  }
}
```

I have read a lot of answers and what i conclude is I somehow need to do something on the server side, however I have no idea what to do since I have SSL certificate (TLS - crt & key) connected with my k8s ingress and can't find any other instructions on what I need to do.